# FeatureRequest different from different Geoserver instances

Tags: geoserver

I have two instances of geoserver on different systems, with the same Data underlying. One is version 2.4.4, the other one 2.6.2.

Both behave different when I make a Feature Request:

the first one is giving me Bounding Box Data like this:

```
<gml:boundedBy><gml:Envelope srsDimension="2" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31466">    
<gml:lowerCorner>5770863.855 363273.177000001</gml:lowerCorner>
<gml:upperCorner>5770864.5512810005 363274.2701699999</gml:upperCorner>      
</gml:Envelope></gml:boundedBy>
```

The second one provides location Data in a different way:

```
<gml:Polygon ...>
  .....
  <gml:posList>
        5770863.855  xxx yyy 363273.177000001 5770864.5512810005 zzz qqq 63274.2701699999 rrr sss
  </gml:posList>   
 ....
</gml:Polygon>
```

I want to have it on both instances like in the first one, with the bounded Box.

Comment: which exact request are you making?

Comment: `http://mygeoserver/myworkspace/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typeName=myworkspace:mylayer`

Comment: Going by memory the default output format has changed I believe.
I believe you should specify GML2 to make sure you get the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at your wfs settings:
(Screenshots of german UI, but should be obvious where to find the options in the english UI,too):

[image]

Make sure you have activated the option that you want to get the bounding box of the features:

[image]

If you also want to define the GML-version you get as response you can add one of the following options to your getFeature-request:

```
&outputFormat=GML2

&outputFormat=text/xml;subtype=gml/3.1.1

&outputFormat=application/gml+xml;version=3.2
```

Comment: Thank you! Although the specified checkbox was NOT checked in the first instance, checking it in the second solved the problem!